# Public function in Singleton calling itself

Tags: javascript, singleton

I'm trying to use a singleton pattern but I am having trouble with implementing a recursive public function.

```
var singleton = (function(){
    var self = this;
    function privateFunc(){
        console.log('I can only be accessed from within!');
    }
    return{
        publicFunc: function(){
            //More stuff here
            setTimeout(self.publicFunc, 1000);
        }
    }
})();
```

I am calling it with `singleton.publicFunc`

I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'publicFunc' of undefined`.

My understanding is `var self` is actually the Window object in this instance, so I have to pass `singleton.publicFunc` as the callback for this to work, but it doesn't seem very "DRY" (Don't repeat yourself). Is there 
a better way to accomplish this while using a singleton?

**With API calls**

```
var wikiAPI = (function(){
    var self = this;
    return {
      getRandomArticle : function() {
        return $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exintro=&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
        });
      },
      fireAPICalls : function() {
        self.getRandomArticle().done(function(data) {
          for(var id in data.query.pages) {
            this.data = data.query.pages[id];
          }
          console.log(this.data);
          setTimeout(self.fireAPICalls, 1000);
        });
      }
    }
  })();
```

Comment: @Jack My mistake, it should have been `publicFunc`, updating question.

Comment: this in IIFE is global window.

You should use bind or closures.

Comment: You could also just create one instance and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr) like so:

```
var singleton = (function(){
    var self = this;
    function privateFunc(){
        console.log('I can only be accessed from within!');
    }
    return{
        publicFunc: function nameVisibleOnlyInsideThisFunction(){
                           //^-------------------------------^
            //More stuff here
            setTimeout(nameVisibleOnlyInsideThisFunction, 1000);
        }
    }
})();
```

---

I just saw your edit. What would help is having a reference to the functions you are trying to call. So how about something like this:

```
var wikiAPI = (function(){
    var self = this;
    var randomArticle = function() {
        return $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exintro=&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
        });
      };
    var repeatFunc = function fireApi() {
        randomArticle().done(function(data) {
          for(var id in data.query.pages) {
            this.data = data.query.pages[id];
          }
          console.log(this.data);
          setTimeout(fireApi, 1000);
        });
      };
    return {
      getRandomArticle : randomArticle,
      fireAPICalls : repeatFunc
    }
  })();
```

Comment: @Thrustmaster Thanks, this worked! An additional question, how would I go about calling another public function from within `publicFunc`? I've tried also using a named function expression but that didn't work because it's not in the same function...

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Accepting answer as this answer fits my question most.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in the `setTimeout()` to bind the function to the right scope:

```
publicFunc: function() {
    setTimeout(this.publicFunc.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/te3Ru/

Comment: `setTimeout(undefined)` doesn’t throw errors in all browsers.

Comment: @David Thanks for the answer! My code still seems to be behaving differently with the error though, I tried to use `bind` in `setTimeout` as suggested but then it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined`. See my updated code at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @theintellects `self` is not the singleton since you defined it in the IIFE. You should probably open a new question if you have follow-ups on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this` in a IIFE. If you want to use `this` properly you need to create an object/instance of a function, like so:

```js
var singleton = (function () {
    // allow to omit "new" when declaring an object
    if (!(this instanceof singleton)) return new singleton();

    var self = this,                      // self now points to "this"
        privateFunc = function () {
            console.log('I can only be accessed from within!');
        };

    this.publicFunc = function() {
        console.log(this);                // this now points to the correct object
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.publicFunc.call(self);   // call function in the "self" scope
        }, 1000);
    };
    return this;
});

singleton().publicFunc();
```

it's not much of a singleton now, but you can have the closest thing to `private` and `public` that javascript has!